# Javascript function to show dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know how to call an dialog function inside function? 
An example, I have code like this and working fine

```
$("body").on("click", "#addItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: 'Add New',
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "900px",
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).load(url); 
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  return false;
}); 

$("body").on("click", "#delItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: 'Delete item?',
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "900px",
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).load(url); 
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  return false;
}); 

$("body").on("click", "#updItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: 'Update item',
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "900px",
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).load(url); 
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  return false;
}); 

$("body").on("click", "#detItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: 'Item Detail',
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "900px",
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).load(url); 
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  return false;
});
```

When I think for a while, I'm realize that's a long script. A long script with recuring same thing.

And now, I think something like this

```
function openDialog(title, url) {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    title: title,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "900px",
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).load(url); 
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  return false;
  })
}

$("body").on("click", "#addItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href'), title = 'some title';
  openDialog(title, url);
}); 

$("body").on("click", "#delItem", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href'), title = 'some title';
  openDialog(title, url);
}); 

etc ...
```

But when I tried to change my code, there's some error. A dialog box appear. But the url not work and the dialog content also empty.

Anyone have an answer? Or there's another method to achieve it?

Thanks

==== edited ====

My bad. I put a wrong order for parameter function. The right order when function declared is the `title` first then the `url`. No wonder there's no content. Now, my code works fine with editable code above. Thanks.

Comment: Is the function declaration a typo here, or is that a copy/paste of the code?  `Function` should not have a capital `F`.  If you look in the browser console there may be an error on that line of code.

Comment: What error exactly? What does the browser console say?

Comment: Ah, pardon my finger. It's my habit to start a paragraph with capitalize letter. But I'm sure when I try that code, there's not a capitalize letter.

Comment: The browser console not say anything. The jQuery modal dialog works fine. But the content not. The dialog have an empty content. The datatables I use is work fine too. If I have an error in one of my javascript code, the datatables should have not work, right?

Comment: Can you show us the full `openDialog()` function?  If the dialog is being opened but has no content then the problem is mostly likely there.

Comment: Thanks Archer, you give me an insight. You're right. The parameter order for `openDialog()` function was not right. First, the parameter is `openDialog(url, title)`. When I change the order, my code works fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  This should be marked as closed as it was just typographical error.